# Setting C/C++ build configuration reverts to default after hitting OK

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, build, eclipse-cdt

I have a set of environment variables I use in all my projects, as well as custom make targets that I use for my builds in Eclipse (Mars 4.5.0).  In order not to have to set these every time, I made a new configuration from a configured project under Project->Properties->C/C++ Build.  However, when I now select that configuration in a new project and hit apply or OK, I find the changes haven't taken effect, and if I open up Project->Properties again, I see it has reverted to the default.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite satisfactory, but in case others have the same issue, I found that one way to deal with the issue is to simply delete the default configuration, so that your custom configuration is the only option.  I'm curious whether this is a bug or whether I'm going about this the wrong way...